# OpenTK Block must be fully assigned

Tags: c#, opentk

Hello I am using c# and opentk and I have this code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using OpenTK;


namespace PlatformGame
{
    struct Level
    {
        private Block[,] grid;
        public Block this[int X, int Y]
        {
            get
            {
                return grid[X, Y];
            }
            set
            {
                grid[X, Y] = value;
            }
        }

        public Point PlayerStartPos;

        private string filename;
        public string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                return filename;
            }
        }


        public int Width
        {
            get
            {
                return grid.GetLength(0);
            }
        }
        public int Height
        {
            get
            {
                return grid.GetLength(1);
            }
        }

        public Level(int Width, int Height)
        {
            grid = new Block[Width, Height];
            filename = "none";
            PlayerStartPos = new Point(1, 1);

            for (int x=0; x< Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
                {
                    if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == Width - 1 || y == Height - 1)
                    {
                        grid[x, y] = new Block(BlockType.Water, x, y);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid[x, y] = new Block(BlockType.Empty, x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public enum BlockType
    {
        Empty,
        Water,
        Grass,
        Dirt,
        Stone,
        Platform,
        Ladder,
        LadderPlatform
    }

    struct Block
    {
        private BlockType type;

        private int PosX, PosY;

        private bool Water, Grass, Dirt, Stone, Platform, Ladder, LadderPlatform;

        public BlockType Type
        {
            get { return type; }
        }

        public int X
        {
            get { return PosX; }
        }
        public int Y
        {
            get { return PosY; }
        }
        public bool IsWater
        {
            get { return Water; }
        }
        public bool IsGrass
        {
            get { return Grass; }
        }
        public bool IsDirt
        {
            get { return Dirt; }
        }
        public bool IsStone
        {
            get { return Stone; }
        }
        public bool IsPlatform
        {
            get { return Platform; }
        }
        public bool IsLadder
        {
            get { return Ladder; }
        }

        public Block(BlockType type,int x,int y)
        {
            this.PosX = x;
            this.PosY = y;
            this.type = type;

            this.Water = false;
            this.Grass = false;
            this.Dirt = false;
            this.Stone = false;
            this.Ladder = false;
            this.Platform = false;

            switch (type)
            {
                case BlockType.Ladder:
                    Ladder = true;
                    break;
                case BlockType.LadderPlatform:
                    Ladder = true;
                    Platform = true;
                    break;
                case BlockType.Platform:
                    Platform = true;
                    break;
                case BlockType.Water:
                    Water = true;
                    break;
                case BlockType.Grass:
                    Grass = true;
                    break;
                case BlockType.Dirt:
                    Dirt = true;
                    break;
                case BlockType.Stone:
                    Stone = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For some reason visual studio is giving me this error at `public Block`

> Field 'Block.LadderPlatform' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller PlatformGame

I have tried to understand the problem but I cant solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss  `this.LadderPlatform = false;` in your initialisation.

If you add this before your `switch` statement in `public Block(BlockType type,int x,int y)`
 it will work

Like this:

```
public Block(BlockType type, int x, int y)
{
    this.PosX = x;
    this.PosY = y;
    this.type = type;

    this.Water = false;
    this.Grass = false;
    this.Dirt = false;
    this.Stone = false;
    this.Ladder = false;
    this.Platform = false;
    this.LadderPlatform = false;  //<--- This is missing

    switch (type)
    {
        case BlockType.Ladder:
            Ladder = true;
            break;
        case BlockType.LadderPlatform:
            Ladder = true;
            Platform = true;
            break;
        case BlockType.Platform:
            Platform = true;
            break;
        case BlockType.Water:
            Water = true;
            break;
        case BlockType.Grass:
            Grass = true;
            break;
        case BlockType.Dirt:
            Dirt = true;
            break;
        case BlockType.Stone:
            Stone = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for wasting you time for a stupid mistake. tks for the help i just need to wait to set as answer.

Comment: You're welcome, sometimes we are all blind to our own code ;)